# Is Google USB Driver a kernel-mode driver?

Tags: android, usb, driver

Is Google USB Driver a kernel-mode driver?
Google USB Driver can be downloaded from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google USB Driver is not a kernel-mode driver.